# Spring JPA Inconsistent Responses

Tags: java, spring, exception, jpa

I have a Spring provide a Rest service, and a webpage calling the Rest endpoints. Behind Spring I have a Mysql database and JPA to access it.

Lately when my webpage calls the endpoints they have been returning inconsistent responses. That is, sometimes the response is the expected result, other times one of two Exceptions.

```
Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC begin transaction failed: 
Could not roll back JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: unexpected error when rollbacking
```

To make matters stranger, when I call the endpoint in the browser manually, I always get the expected response.
My webpage is calling 6 or 7 endpoints in a very short amount of time, could that be the issue? If not, any idea what might be causing this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

From this, it is quite possible that your database is getting too many requests, and the requests are timeouted, and that causes the exception. However, you can only be sure if you also check the logs of the database, as it would provide information on why the connection is dropped.

If this is the case, you can go for a number of approaches:

- increase the timeout time on the side of the web container and/or the database
- try to lower the number of request to the database
- optimize the connection pools, so you do not hit timeouts